# Kubernetes with Calico Gitlab Runner Pods can't reach external API

Tags: networking, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, calico

I've deployed a bare-metal Kubernetes cluster with Calico networking. I'm successfully able to communicate between pods and from external network to pods using Ingress. When I use Dashboard EXEC function the pod is able to fetch external resource (DNS works, PING works, CURL works), but the pod process itself is failing.

What should I check next? Do you need more info to analyze it?

**UPDATE**

Issue is related to Gitlab Runner only.

Comment: What do you mean by Dashboard EXEC? You execute a shell command in the running container?

Comment: @weibeld At Kubernetes Dashboard at Pod detail there is EXEC button at top right corner. I assume it opens bash in the container.

Comment: @JanZahradník what do you mean by "pod process itself is failing"? Could you provide output of `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`

Answer (score 1):

Finally it turned out that the problem was not with whole Kubernetes cluster, but related only to Gitlab Runner. Thanks to this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3705) it works again:

Successfully able to complete builds by adding the network to the build command `--network host`

```
build:
  script: 
    - docker build --network host .
```

This requires a `.gitlab-ci.yml` and excludes autodevops.